# Regex grouping rules for alternation

Tags: regex, pcre

How does a regular expression engine know that the following:

```
lions|starz|summit
```

Is grouped as:

```
(?:lions)|(?:starz)|(?:summit)
```

And not, something like:

```
lion(?:s|s)tar(?:z|s)ummit
```

Is there a rule about alternation that describes 'how far back' it should go or how is that determined?

Comment: | is the clear demarkation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe symbol (`|`) is a special character, which cannot be used in the phrase you're trying to match unless you escape it.

So, the regex engine reads characters that are not special, until it reaches one that is and decides what to do from there.

In your case, it reads up to and including `lions`, then finds a special `|`, telling it there's an alternative following, which is `starz`, followed by another special `|`, indicating a next alternative.

So, once it's done it knows it needs to match any of `lions`, `starz` and `summit`.

The reason it doesn't mistake it for something like `lion(?:s|s)tar(?:z|s)ummit` is simply because you didn't provide it with the special characters `(`, `?`, etc. - so there's no confusion.

And there is no rule about "how far back" it needs to go, if anything it just keeps going forward from the first character until it hits something that tells it to stop. You could have 100s of alternatives and it would still match any of them.

If you wanted to match a text that had a pipe symbol in it instead, you'd escape it with a backslash (`\`), like `before\|after`

Answer (score 0):

The other answer explains how a regex engine might process a regex with alternation.

> Is there a rule about alternation that describes 'how far back' it should go or how is that determined?

The answer to that question is, yes, there is a rule for that. It matches as far back and forward as possible. For example, the [GNU AWK manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operator-Details.html) says:

> |
>
> This is the alternation operator and it is used to specify alternatives. The ‘|’ has the lowest precedence of all the regular expression operators. For example, ‘^P|[aeiouy]’ matches any string that matches either ‘^P’ or ‘[aeiouy]’. This means it matches any string that starts with ‘P’ or contains (anywhere within it) a lowercase English vowel.
>
> **The alternation applies to the largest possible regexps on either side.**

Emphasis on the last sentence.

One might also ask, "why was it defined that way?"

Probably because it's far more convenient that way. So you can write `foo|bar` instead of having to write `(?:foo)|(?:bar)`, when you want to match "foo or bar" without capturing groups.